# Use models from openapi-python-client as response models

Tags: python, fastapi, openapi, pydantic

i have some openapi schema from which i generated python client (or SDK) with [this](https://github.com/openapi-generators/openapi-python-client). This also generates "models" or type hints that you can use like this

```
data: GetUserMeResponse200 = get_user_me.sync(client=client)
```

this works etc but i would like to use this class as a response_model so user can see what type of data he can expect in swagger.

Is there any way or a hack that i can use this class, I really would prefer not to write pydantic models when i got everything that i need generated

**this is the class**

```
@_attrs_define
class GetUserMeResponse200:
    """
    Attributes:
        id (str):
        email (str):
        first_name (Union[None, str]):
        created_at (datetime.datetime):
        updated_at (datetime.datetime):
    """

    id: str
    email: str
    first_name: Union[None, str]
    created_at: datetime.datetime
    updated_at: datetime.datetime
    additional_properties: Dict[str, Any] = _attrs_field(init=False, factory=dict)

    def to_dict(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        id = self.id

        email = self.email

        first_name: Union[None, str]
        first_name = self.first_name

        last_name: Union[None, str]
        last_name = self.last_name

        created_at = self.created_at.isoformat()

        updated_at = self.updated_at.isoformat()


        field_dict: Dict[str, Any] = {}
        field_dict.update(self.additional_properties)
        field_dict.update(
            {
                "id": id,
                "email": email,
                "firstName": first_name,
                "createdAt": created_at,
                "updatedAt": updated_at,
            }
        )

        return field_dict

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls: Type[T], src_dict: Dict[str, Any]) -> T:

        d = src_dict.copy()
        id = d.pop("id")

        email = d.pop("email")


        def _parse_first_name(data: object) -> Union[None, str]:
            if data is None:
                return data
            return cast(Union[None, str], data)

        first_name = _parse_first_name(d.pop("firstName"))

        created_at = isoparse(d.pop("createdAt"))

        updated_at = isoparse(d.pop("updatedAt"))

        get_api_v1_private_user_me_response_200 = cls(
            id=id,
            email=email,
            first_name=first_name,
            created_at=created_at,
            updated_at=updated_at,
        )

        get_api_v1_private_user_me_response_200.additional_properties = d
        return get_api_v1_private_user_me_response_200

    @property
    def additional_keys(self) -> List[str]:
        return list(self.additional_properties.keys())

    def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> Any:
        return self.additional_properties[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key: str, value: Any) -> None:
        self.additional_properties[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key: str) -> None:
        del self.additional_properties[key]

    def __contains__(self, key: str) -> bool:
        return key in self.additional_properties
```

**update**

i got it working by

```
TestModel = create_model(
    "TestModel",
    **{attr: (Type[GetUserMeResponse200], ...) for attr in GetUserMeResponse200.__annotations__}
)
```